# Ansible - what is the purpose of the key "run_once" in a task file.yml?

Tags: linux, mysql, php, web-server, ansible

In a task file whose role is to install php on a remote server(s)

someone uses this module (after the one dedicated to the installation) to update the fresh install :

```
  command:
    php update.php --quick
  run_once: yes
  delegate_to: "{{item}}"
  with_items: "{{servernetwork.nodes}}"
```

So what I don't get is that afaik, Ansible scripted tasks natively have 3 outcomes when parsed (when the script is launched onto the remote server) : something like either

- *ok* (has already been done before that call),

- *changed* (this is a new requirement so it just has been done),

- or I don't remember the *third state*.

But whatever, because basically Ansible will natively do only the steps of the recipe that are missing on the current state of the server. Docs and people like to use the word << indempotent >> for this delta-like behavior.

So why do we need to precize `run_once` ? Did I miss something about its key concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`run_once` by a [documentation is the following](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once):

> In some cases there may be a need to only run a task **one time** for a batch of hosts. This can be achieved by configuring `run_once` on a task.
>   [Bolding is mine.]

```yaml
- command: /opt/application/upgrade_db.py
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: web01.example.org
```

---

It has a broad set of use-cases.

- **Apply database migrations**. (It does not make any sense to apply migrations on each hosts. One is completely sufficient)
- **Create a database backup**. Running a playbook on batch of hosts, it would be valuable to make a backup on one of these.
- **Make such an API-call that requires to be run from specific hosts.** (And make it once...)
- [...]

It is very often used with [`local_action`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) or [`delegate_to`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation). In this case, you run action on batch of hosts but executes it `locally` or completely somewhere else.

---

*Idempotence* is something completely not directly related to `run_once`

By definition *Idempotence* is such a operation `f(x)`, that if `f(x)=y`, then `f(f(x))=y`. By human understanding, we can say that applying this function twice on same argument, it does not change a result. You can think of function like a role and `y` is a result of your code.

Answer (score 1):

run_once means this will be executed on the first node from servernetwork.node list and then its results ( variables/facts) will be used for all hosts in the list. And it won't be executed on other nodes ( apart from the first one).